# Proguard [ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Overflow of unsigned short value ]

Tags: android, proguard

Gradle ver : 3.4.1
JDK ver : 1.8
Proguard ver : 5.3.3
Android gradle plugin 2.3.+ 
I am getting exception in build due to proguard. I have tried proguard 5.3.2 also but with no success.

Here is my release config

```
release {
        debuggable false
        android.buildTypes.release.proguardFiles = []
        proguardFile 'proguard-android.txt'
        //minifyEnabled
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.release
    }
```

Following is the exeption

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Overflow of unsigned short value [95001]
at proguard.classfile.io.RuntimeDataOutput.writeUnsignedShort(RuntimeDataOutput.java:213)
at proguard.classfile.io.ProgramClassWriter$AttributeBodyWriter.visitLineNumberInfo(ProgramClassWriter.java:565)
at proguard.classfile.attribute.LineNumberTableAttribute.lineNumbersAccept(LineNumberTableAttribute.java:171)
```

PS: I can build with android gradle plugin 2.2.+ that is using lower version of proguard I think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue ([PGD-681](https://sourceforge.net/p/proguard/bugs/681/)) was fixed in [Proguard v6.0](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/versions).

However, Android Plugin for Gradle v3.1.0 is still using Proguard v5.3.3. You can check it running `./gradlew buildEnvironment`:

```
classpath
+--- com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0
|    \--- com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.0
...
|         +--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3
|         |    \--- net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.3.3
```

So you have to manually include the latest version of Proguard:

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2') {
    exclude module: 'proguard-gradle'
}
classpath('net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3') {
    force = true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Manually set proguard version to 5.2.1

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0') {
    exclude module: 'proguard-gradle'
}
classpath('net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.2.1') {
    force = true
}
```

[Reference](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37138815#comment4)